# Buttons not aligning to center (HTML / CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am currently making a website for a game that a friend is making. I am using materialize for many parts of the website such as buttons for social media. My problem is that I am trying to align all my buttons in the center of the screen but they are not centering and are moving slightly from left to right when I change resolution. 
Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m4 l8" align="middle">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4">Download</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4" href="https://discord.gg/xRqFGEK">Discord</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4" href="http://www.twitter.com/playparadon">Twitter</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4" href="http://www.instagram.com/playparadon">Instagram</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 col s12 m4 l8{
  display: flex; justify-content: center;
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSw3k.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: apply a specific class just for centring buttons , i.e: `btn-center` and access it via `.` like this `.btn-center` in css

Comment: The code is actually working. Maybe it conflicts with some other codes inside your website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector for that should be

```
.col.s12.m4.l8 { ... }
```

(leading dots for the classes, and no spaces in between, since all these classes belong to the same element)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding . to your selectors, in the CSS.
So .col, .s12, etc.

More info. on this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/jgrishey/fgw2ho5f/

Seems to work here when you have . in front of your classes in the CSS.

Just to give a little information:

. and # are used to identify classes and id's respectively in CSS.

If your element has an id="myId" or a class="myClass" then you refer to that element as:

`.myClass {}`

or

`#myId {}`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use .push-l3 on large screen and play with the rest.

like

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m4 l8 push-l3">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-center btn-large #212121 grey darken-4">Download</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4" href="https://discord.gg/xRqFGEK">Discord</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4" href="http://www.twitter.com/playparadon">Twitter</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large #212121 grey darken-4" href="http://www.instagram.com/playparadon">Instagram</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think it is about screen size. I think some other code is preventing them to be centered properly.

Comment: test suggestion: use # id instead and give your div a bgcolor to see what's happening.

Comment: Yeah this might actually work.
Guess: I think nothing is wrong with your code but maybe your "container" is not full width and it has some space from right. So when you put your html code inside  your container, it actually centers buttons but since there are some space from right side of the screen, you see it like not centered. To see that, I suggest you to use **Developer Tools** of your browser. You probably will see the problem there. Can you also provide html code?